# selective display of the groups text on a stacked ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, stacked-chart, geom-text

I'm creating several stacked barplots using ggplot. I'm grouping my results by year and I want to sort my data by a factor variable that has many levels (around 30). I want to display my cumulative summs but there are so many of them that they overlap.

My barplot looks OK for categories with big values, but I haven't managed to find a solution for categories that have small values.I tried setting different geom_text arguments. Now I would like to simply exclude the text for those categories from the barplot but dont know how.

```
ggplot(data=pivot, aes(x=YEAR, y=SUM, fill=GROUP))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=round(SUM)), vjust=1.6,
        position = position_stack(), size=2.5)+
  labs(x = "YEAR", y="Amount sold in EUR")
```

I think that my graphs look better with text over categories with bigger values so I want to include them in the final results but don't know how to select only a few for display.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
> pivot
```

A tibble: 86 x 3
 Groups:   value [31]
   value Year      SUM
       
 1 1     2011   771.
 2 1     2012   999.
 3 1     2013  1479.
 4 1     2014   512.
 5 1     2015   677.
 6 3     2012   4.07
 7 4     2012   7.92
 8 4     2013   3.97
 9 4     2014   41.2
10 5     2011   12.0
 ... with 76 more rows

I would like to display text on the barplot for values of SUM for category 1 as they are bigger but not for categories 3, 4 and 5. In the final result I would be content with displaying text only for categories 1, 24 and 26 but dont know how to select only them.

Comment: without your data is is hard to answer your question. Can you please share your data using `dput`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie and maybe not using dput correctly as it gives me a very long result. I added the head of my dataframe to the question if it helps. I can't unfortunatelly not post my plot.

Comment: The output of `dput` is supposed to be quite long, you can still copy it here or do `dput(head(yourdata))` so we can recreate your problem. It is quite hard to properly understand otherwise. A first pointer that might help: Have you tried the `check_overlap` argument from geom_text?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn’t used check_overlap and it offers a nice solution to my problem. The text of the categories has disappeared but the important ones with bigger values are labelled.